# How to write clear INSERT VALUE queries for MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on INSERTing VALUES using MySQL queries that involve escaping values via a PHP script.  I was able write code that works (see below), but the only ways I can figure out are so cumbersome that they remind me of plebs eating peas off a fork at West Point. I have to believe I'm missing something. MySQL and PHP are supposed to work together, right?  Can anyone point me in a better direction?  Thanks!

```
<?php
// CONNECTION = "$connection".
require("Connection.php");
// CREATE TABLE
$create_table_query="
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `titles_table`
(lastpost_id INT(10) NULL,
title VARCHAR(200))
";
$create_query_results=mysqli_query($connection,$create_table_query);

// Set up CUMBERSOME query:
$title1="IL - Yingying Zhang, 26, Urbana, 9 June 2017";
Echo "\$title1 looks like: $title1 <br>"; // 'IL - Yingying Zhang, 26, Urbana, 9 June 2017' 
$title2="NJ - Brendan Creato, 3, found dead in Cooper River Park, 13 Oct 2015";
Echo "\$title2 looks like: $title2 <br>";  // 'NJ - Brendan Creato, 3, found dead in Cooper River Park, 13 Oct 2015' 

$title1_escaped="'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$title1)."'";
Echo "\$title1_escaped looks like: $title1_escaped <br>";
$title2_escaped="'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$title2)."'";
Echo "\$title2_escaped looks like: $title2_escaped <br>";

$sql_query_CUMBERSOME="
INSERT INTO `titles_table`(
lastpost_id,
title
)
VALUES
(1013,
$title1_escaped),
(1014,
$title2_escaped);
";

echo "<br>";
echo "Here's what \$sql_query_CUMBERSOME looks like :<br>";
echo "$sql_query_CUMBERSOME </br>";
// INSERT INTO `titles_table`( lastpost_id, title ) VALUES (1013, 'IL - Yingying Zhang, 26, Urbana, 9 June 2017'), (1014, 'NJ - Brendan Creato, 3, found dead in Cooper River Park, 13 Oct 2015'); 

// RUN and TEST $sql_query_CUMBERSOME
$sql_query_CUMBERSOME_results=mysqli_query($connection,$sql_query_CUMBERSOME);
// TEST the results (the tests report success)
IF(!$sql_query_CUMBERSOME_results):
    $results_error_message=mysqli_error($connection);
    ECHO "ERROR: \$sql_query_CUMBERSOME_results doesn't exist. The mysqli error message is: $results_error_message </br>";
ELSE: 
    $affected_rows=mysqli_affected_rows($connection);
    ECHO "SUCCESS: \$sql_query_CUMBERSOME_results exists. Here is the affected rows count: $affected_rows </br></br>";
ENDIF;
// -----------------------------------

// SET UP alternative UNWIELDLY query:
$sql_query_UNWIELDLY = "INSERT INTO `titles_table`(lastpost_id,title) ";
$sql_query_UNWIELDLY .= "VALUES (1015,'";
$sql_query_UNWIELDLY .= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,'IL - Yingying Zhang, 26, Urbana, 9 June 2017');
$sql_query_UNWIELDLY .= "'),";
$sql_query_UNWIELDLY .= "(1016,'";
$sql_query_UNWIELDLY .= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,'NJ - Brendan Creato, 3, found dead in Cooper River Park, 13 Oct 2015');
$sql_query_UNWIELDLY .= "');";

echo "Here's what \$sql_query_UNWIELDLY looks like:<br>";
echo "$sql_query_UNWIELDLY </br>";
// INSERT INTO `titles_table`(lastpost_id,title) VALUES (1015,'IL - Yingying Zhang, 26, Urbana, 9 June 2017'),(1016,'NJ - Brendan Creato, 3, found dead in Cooper River Park, 13 Oct 2015'); 

// RUN and TEST $sql_query_UNWIELDLY
$sql_query_UNWIELDLY_results=mysqli_query($connection,$sql_query_UNWIELDLY);
// TEST the results (the tests report success)
IF(!$sql_query_UNWIELDLY_results):
    $results_error_message=mysqli_error($connection);
    ECHO "3a) ERROR: \$sql_query_UNWIELDLY_results doesn't exist. The mysqli error message is: $results_error_message </br>";
ELSE: 
    $affected_rows=mysqli_affected_rows($connection);
    echo "SUCCESS: \$sql_query_UNWIELDLY_results exists. Here is the affected rows count: $affected_rows </br>";
ENDIF; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the line of code looks good but, Only things we can use to close the connection after use.

End of your code add 
mysqli_close($connection);

hope it will work, if not let me know.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my code.  Good point about closing the connection.   The code does work as is, but is so cumbersome that I'm worried that I'm learning a dumb approach.  So far, however, (apart from dhakaboy's suggestion about using PDO) no one has suggested a better way, so maybe I'm not that far off.

Comment: My concern only check your code is running or not? but on the bottom line If you want to do better approach, I would suggest, start making PHP classes with the singleton pattern. Learn how to use singleton it will help you to do better approach.